# VBA Code to convert PowerPoint file as Window Media player file

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I would like to save PowerPoint file (pptx) as Window Media video(.wmv) through Excel VBA Code. Is it possible to convert file by VBA?

Comment: Please include the Excel VBA sample code that you are using to work on PowerPoint files. Btw, PowerPoint has its own VBA, so why are you using Excel VBA for this purpose? Please clarify.

Comment: If you're using Office 2013 or higher, you can use  [Presentation.CreateVideo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746354.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, you can create a procedure as follows:

```
Public Sub CreateVideo()
    Dim papp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim p As PowerPoint.Presentation

    Set papp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

    Set p = papp.Presentations.Open("mypresentation.pptx")

    p.CreateVideo "myvideo.wmv"
End Sub
```

**Important note**: In the VBA editor, you need to select *"Options"* -> *"References"*; and there you need to check *"Microsoft Powerpoint 15.0 Object Library"*. Otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sub CreateEmotionalIntelligencePresentation()
Dim pptApp As Object
Dim pptPresentation As Object
Dim slideIndex As Integer

```
' Create PowerPoint application
Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
pptApp.Visible = True

' Create a new presentation
Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Add

' Slide 1: Title Slide
SetTitleSlide pptPresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle), "Emotional Intelligence", "Understanding and Nurturing Emotions"

' Slide 2: What is Emotional Intelligence?
SetContentSlide pptPresentation.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutText), "What is Emotional Intelligence?", "Emotional Intelligence (EI) is the ability to understand and manage one's own emotions and empathize with others."

' Slide 3: Components of Emotional Intelligence
SetContentSlide pptPresentation.Slides.Add(3, ppLayoutText), "Components of Emotional Intelligence", "1. Self-awareness\n2. Self-regulation\n3. Motivation\n4. Empathy\n5. Social skills"

' Slide 4: Importance of Emotional Intelligence
SetContentSlide pptPresentation.Slides.Add(4, ppLayoutText), "Importance of Emotional Intelligence", "EI enhances interpersonal relationships, communication, and leadership skills. It contributes to overall well-being and success."

' Slide 5: Developing Emotional Intelligence
SetContentSlide pptPresentation.Slides.Add(5, ppLayoutText), "Developing Emotional Intelligence", "1. Practice self-reflection\n2. Develop active listening skills\n3. Cultivate empathy\n4. Manage stress effectively"

' Slide 6: Case Studies
SetContentSlide pptPresentation.Slides.Add(6, ppLayoutText), "Case Studies", "Explore real-world examples of individuals or organizations applying emotional intelligence to achieve positive outcomes."

' Slide 7: Conclusion
SetContentSlide pptPresentation.Slides.Add(7, ppLayoutText), "Conclusion", "Embrace and cultivate emotional intelligence for personal and professional growth."
```

End Sub

Sub SetTitleSlide(slide As Object, title As String, subtitle As String)
slide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = title
slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = subtitle
End Sub

Sub SetContentSlide(slide As Object, title As String, content As String)
slide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = title
slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = content
End Sub

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub PreencherApresentacao()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    
    ' Inicializar o PowerPoint
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add
    
    ' Adicionar slides e preencher com conteúdo
    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, 11) ' 11 representa o tipo de slide (texto)
    With pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Utilização de Robô na Usinagem"
        .Font.Size = 24
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    
    ' Slide sobre a importância da automação e robótica na fabricação mecânica
    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(2, 11)
    With pptSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Automação e Robótica na Indústria de Fabricação Mecânica"
        .Font.Size = 18
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    With pptSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "A automação e a robótica desempenham um papel crucial na indústria de fabricação mecânica moderna. Elas permitem a realização de tarefas complexas e repetitivas com precisão, velocidade, eficiência e segurança. Além disso, proporcionam flexibilidade para se adaptar a diferentes demandas de produção, aumentando a competitividade das empresas."
        .Font.Size = 14
    End With
    
    ' Slide sobre a utilização de robôs na usinagem
    Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(3, 11)
    With pptSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Utilização de Robôs na Usinagem"
        .Font.Size = 18
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    With pptSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange
        .Text = "Os robôs na usinagem são dispositivos programáveis capazes de executar tarefas complexas e repetitivas com alta precisão. Eles oferecem diversas vantagens, como maior velocidade de produção, eficiência aprimorada, flexibilidade para lidar com diferentes processos de usinagem e níveis de segurança aprimorados. Sua utilização contribui para a melhoria da qualidade das peças e para a redução dos custos de produção."
        .Font.Size = 14
    End With
    
    ' Adicionar mais slides com exemplos, aplicações, sistemas robóticos, desafios e considerações, etc.
    
    ' Salvar e exibir a apresentação
    pptPres.SaveAs "C:\Caminho\Para\Salvar\Apresentacao.pptx" ' Substitua pelo caminho desejado
    pptPres.Close
    pptApp.Quit
    
    ' Liberar memória
    Set pptSlide = Nothing
    Set pptPres = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "A apresentação foi gerada com sucesso!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Your reply appears to generate a PowerPoint file but doesn't create a video from it, which was OP's original request. Please either update it to answer the original question or remove it.  Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```vb
Sub SpeedTimeGraph()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPres As Object
    Dim slideIndex As Integer

    ' Create a new instance of PowerPoint
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = True ' Show PowerPoint application

    ' Add a new presentation
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add

    ' Add a title slide
    Set slide1 = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitle)
    slide1.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Speed-Time Graph"

    ' Add a content slide
    Set slide2 = pptPres.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutText)
    slide2.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Time (s)"
    slide2.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Speed (m/s)"

    ' Add a chart to the content slide
    Set chartShape = slide2.Shapes.AddChart2(Type:=xlXYScatterLines)

    ' Set data for the chart
    chartShape.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$10")

    ' Customize chart labels and title
    chartShape.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    chartShape.Chart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Time (s)"
    chartShape.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    chartShape.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Speed (m/s)"
    chartShape.Chart.HasTitle = True
    chartShape.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Speed-Time Graph"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this is an answer to the question?